# Unique Primary Id exchange in on mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i got an sql table which contains data for a menu in the php page.

```
 SELECT * FROM `hizlierisim` ORDER BY id LIMIT 0 , 10
```

it is ordered by id row.but im asked to add order control on admin panel.
So there will Up&Down Buttons to re-arrange menu items.

i guess there is two ways to do this

one is to create a row called 'order' and change sql query to:

```
SELECT * FROM `hizlierisim` ORDER BY `order` LIMIT 0 , 10
```

or

exchange id's of the columns that we wanted to move.
and still use same sql:

```
SELECT * FROM `hizlierisim` ORDER BY id LIMIT 0 , 10
```

id method seems easier but i wonder if there is a possibility to exchange id's of two columns on mysql?

Comment: I am not clear on what you mean by exchange Id column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Messing with primary key fields just to satisfy some arbitrary ordering requirement is a bad idea. Especially in a foreign key situation. Add an 'order' column (which is a reserved word, by the way, so use something else if you want to save yourself some pain) is the practical option.

Answer (score 3):

Changing PK IDs for this sort of functionality is a very bad practice; far better to introduce an ordering column and use that to sort by.  Obviously don't call it ORDER as that's a reserved word...

Answer (score 3):

The id of a row should be static, a permanent unique identifier for the record, such that it can be stored as a foreign key elsewhere.

Creating the "order_id" as you suggest would be preferable.  This can be changed to any value you like without a side-effect, it's for ordering, changing it only effects ordering.

In terms of "swapping" values, there isn't anything I'm aware of, you just need to code it yourself.

Either...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE x SET order_id = NULL WHERE order_id = 11
UPDATE x SET order_id = 11   WHERE order_id = 10
UPDATE x SET order_id = 10   WHERE order_id IS NULL

COMMIT TRANSACTION

(or similar)
```

Or maybe something like...

```
UPDATE
  x
SET
  order_id = CASE order_id WHEN 11 then 10 ELSE 11 END
WHERE
  order_id IN (10,11)
```

Comment: If the order must be unique and not null, it is a way to do the exchange without search for a value not in use (to use temporally)?

Comment: @PhoneixS - Try the second version using a single update statement.  If that fails then you're going to have to do something to find that unused value.  *(Possibly just using 0 or -1 or a value you **know** will never be used.)*

Comment: Thanks with the second it run Ok. I was thinking wrong that internally the UPDATE do it in two steps, but by mysql server is like one step.

Answer (score 2):

By "exchange" I assume you're talking about updating primary key values of two columns which is horrible, HORRIBLE idea - I can't stress enough how bad it is and what implications it might have. I suggest you do some reading on what primary keys are and why you should never play with them.

Add another field and update it with values 0, 1 and so on and order on that column. You can also specify multiple columns in your ORDER BY clause which allows you to order by primary key and some other column(s).